# Why Am I not getting expected output?

Tags: binary-tree

I am a beginner in trees.I defined a findNode function to return the node.Then I recursively check if both node as root and subtree is same.But I have not getting the expected output for the below test case. How can it be altered.
Thanks in advance

Expected output:true

Input: Tree:[1,1]

subTree:[1]

but the output I am getting is false

leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/submissions/

````
    def findNode(self,root,subRoot):
        if root==None:
            return None
        if root.val==subRoot.val:
            return root
        if root.left:
            return self.findNode(root.left,subRoot)
        if root.right:
            return self.findNode(root.right,subRoot)
        
    def check(self,root,subRoot):
        if root==None and subRoot==None:
            return True
        if root==None or subRoot==None:
            return False
        if root.val!=subRoot.val:
            return False
        return self.check(root.right,subRoot.right) and self.check(root.left,subRoot.left)
    
    def isSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], subRoot: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        node=self.findNode(root,subRoot)
        return self.check(node,subRoot)
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem in your code because once you find a matching node with `subRoot` node you stop searching and you run `check()` function, which can return `false` and your program will return that `false` without checking deeper subtrees, which can be matched. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def findMatchingTree(self,root,subRoot):
        if root==None:
            return False
        return self.check(root, subRoot) or self.findMatchingTree(root.left,subRoot) or self.findMatchingTree(root.right,subRoot)
        
    def check(self,root,subRoot):
        if root==None and subRoot==None:
            return True
        if root==None or subRoot==None:
            return False
        if root.val!=subRoot.val:
            return False
        return self.check(root.right,subRoot.right) and self.check(root.left,subRoot.left)
    
    def isSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], subRoot: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        return self.findMatchingTree(root,subRoot)
```

If you want to make code faster I suggests you to search for roots from the leafs of tree.